# Set a TTL for an Aerospike large list from node.js client

Tags: ttl, aerospike

Is there a way to set a time-to-live for a large list from aerospike node.js client? Same question for a sub record in a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a GitHub repo [aerospike/LDT-TTL-example](https://github.com/aerospike/LDT-TTL-example) containing an example of setting a TTL on LList objects.

See [How to implement Time To Live (TTL) on LDT elements: example](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/how-to-implement-time-to-live-ttl-on-ldt-elements-example/1672).

Comment: Thanks ronen even  though it's in java I can change it to node.js part and keep the udf part